# How to refresh form after selecting value from combobox

Tags: sql, vb.net, vba, localdb

I would like to know if it is possible to refresh the current windows form I am at after selecting another value from the combo box in order to display the details of that item onto several other textboxes?

So my table looks like
table name : program
program_id program_name program_desc
    1           T1          desc1

This is the code i am using atm

```
Dim connection As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
    connection.ConnectionString = "pathway"
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader
    Dim prognamedesc As String
    Dim filetypetxt As String

    Dim prognamecombo As String
    Dim filetypecombo1 As String
    Dim command As New SqlCommand
    Dim querycommand As New SqlCommand
    connection.Open()
    'THIS SECTION LOADS DATA FROM THE TABLES'
    Try

        command.Connection = connection
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        command.CommandText = "select program_name,filetype from program order by program_name; select * from filetype"
        querycommand.Connection = connection
        querycommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        querycommand.CommandText = "select program_name,program_desc , filetype from program where program_name like" & FiletypeComboBox1.SelectedItem & ""

        dr = command.ExecuteReader

        While dr.Read()

            prognamecombo = dr(0)
            Program_nameComboBox.Items.Add(prognamecombo)

        End While

        dr.NextResult()
        While dr.Read()
            filetypecombo1 = dr(0)
            FiletypeComboBox1.Items.Add(filetypecombo1)
            FiletypeComboBox1.SelectedItem = filetypecombo1
        End While
        dr.NextResult()
        While dr.Read()
            filetypetxt = dr(0)
            FiletypeLabel1.Text = filetypetxt

        End While
        dr.NextResult()
        While dr.Read()
            prognamedesc = dr(0)
            Program_descTextBox.Text = prognamedesc
        End While

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try





    connection.Close()
```

I was wondering if this is doable using the current code?

Comment: What you are after is probably an event procedure. A procedure that gets triggered after a combobox selection was changed. There should be an event you can look up it's called `_Changed()` event of the Combobox control.

Comment: Is it the one where i create another private sub and pass the results onto the output areas? From my understanding, once i select an item from the combo box, the page needs to refresh with the information that is tied to the item in the combo box. I have tried requery but somehow it does not show up at all. me.refresh does nothing as well.

Comment: Google it :) there are tons of informations and tutorials on event procedures in VBA

Comment: Been on Google for several hours before I decided to ask. I have seen an example on Youtube, however it required me to change the entire structure of the program.

Comment: I'm thinking if this might work 
Detect if the combobox has been clicked
Somehow send a new query and display the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement this you have to do two things, First put all your code inside a method and call it something like RefreshForm()

```
public void RefreshForm()
{
  // your code and binding goes here
}
```

The second step is by using selected index changed event over combobox you just call the method that includes all your binding code.

Comment: Sorry I'm very bad at this. The current location of the huge chunk of code placed in a sub that loads immediately when the form loads. So do i just copy it and place it in that refreshform() class and then place the selected index changed event in the main load area?

Comment: Thank you so much! it worked! Now I have to find a way to requery to page when i add a new entry onto the combo box.

Comment: you don't need to double the work, call the same function RefreshForm() on load event.. in this case you have one place to maintain everything